# PHP expected parameter to be a resource

Tags: php, mysql

Just wondering why I am getting this error.

> `Warning: mysql_result() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in C:\wamp\www\Active\Formula One\script\blog.php on line 37`

Used some debugging to get this further error

`You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ''categories' WHERE 'name' = 'nocat'' at line 1`

**blog.php** - Just a snippet of the code so not to fill the page

```
function category_exists($name) {
    $name = mysql_real_escape_string($name);

    $query = mysql_query("SELECT COUNT(1) FROM 'categories' WHERE 'name' = '{$name}'");

    echo mysql_error();

    return ( mysql_result($query, 0) == '0' ) ? false : true; 
}

function add_category($name) {
    $name = mysql_real_escape_string($name);

    mysql_query("INSERT INTO 'blog_categories' SET 'name' = '{$name}'");

}
```

Any help will be appreciated. And a merry Christmas.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use backticks for column and table names instead of quotes

```
mysql_query("SELECT COUNT(1) FROM `categories` WHERE `name` = '{$name}'");
```

If you use quotes it will be interpreted as string and not as name.

And you mixed up `insert` and `update` syntax. Use

```
mysql_query("INSERT INTO `blog_categories` (`name`) values ('{$name}'");
```